# How can I change the background color of the address bar in Chrome?

Tags: firefox, browser, google-chrome, firefox-addon, google-chrome-extension

I'd like to change the background color of Chrome's address bar to black (with grey text). I've done this on Firefox through modifying `userChrome-example.css` and was wondering if there's an equivalent method for Chrome?

Comment: See also: http://superuser.com/questions/341883

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, as far as I know, this is not possible. All I can suggest is this: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/themes.html

Answer (score 0):

FIREFOX and IE: http://www.ehow.com/how_6673791_change-color-address-bar.html

CHROME: It's address bar inherit your operating system's coloring scheme, so you just have to change your window background color. 
Now I'd suggest a gray or dark blue background instead, because the text of the address bar cannot change color as easily and will likely remain black.
I currently have a gray background in my Chrome browser with the "DarkVibe" theme.