# How to change internet browser title bar bgColor

Tags: javascript, html, titlebar

I changed the title bar background color using html: 
but it is not working...

Comment: Do you mean the browser-title bar? I don't think that can be done.

Comment: Not possible. This has been asked earlier;

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479299/how-can-i-change-the-background-color-of-the-address-bar-in-chrome

Comment: @sam That question was about the address bar, whereas this one is about the title bar.  So, it's not the same question.

Answer (score 4):

You can't.

HTML defines the website.

The title bar is part of the browser application, not the website.  You have no control over the application.

Answer (score 2):

You can't set it except if your site is pinned with IE 9/10:

```
<meta name="msapplication-navbutton-color" content="#FF3300" />
```

But it only sets the color of the navigation buttons.

More information on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg491732(v=vs.85).aspx

Pin for example [Cut the Rope](http://www.cuttherope.ie/) to your taskbar and open it.