# Change or invert colors in Chrome address bar for Mac

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, customization, address-bar

I am trying to change or invert the color scheme of my Chrome address bar on Mac.

The Themes in the Google Chrome Store do not have this effect.

Ideal sweet customized address bar

[image]

Or even better would be to customize it myself...

[image]

Anyone know?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change the background color of the address bar in Chrome?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479299/how-can-i-change-the-background-color-of-the-address-bar-in-chrome)